# XPlot scatter chart group by string xaxis

Tags: f#

In the example below is it possible to group the x axis by the strings String1 and String2 instead of each string being its own point?

```
let sales = [
        "String1", 1000;
        "String1", 1200;
        "String2", 1170; 
        "String2", 660; 
        "String2", 1030]

sales
    |> Chart.Scatter
    |> Chart.Show
```

To clarify with the code above I get the following output:
[image: Graph1]

But with the following code the points are grouped:

```
let sales = [
    1, 1000;
    1, 1200;
    2, 1170; 
    2, 660; 
    2, 1030]
sales
    |> Chart.Scatter
    |> Chart.Show
```

[image: Gaph2]

Comment: not sure that I understand what are you talking about

Comment: (I never used XPlot, so it maybe a reason)

Comment: I've updated it, with an example, hopefully this will help

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `List.map` function, I believe:

```
    let sales = [
    "Sales1", 1000;
    "Sales1", 1200;
    "Sales2", 1170; 
    "Sales2", 660; 
    "Sales2", 1030]

let myscatter = 
    Scatter(
        x = List.map fst sales,
        y = List.map snd sales,
        mode = "markers"
   )

myscatter
|> Chart.Plot
|> Chart.Show
```

[image: chart]

Indentation is being awful on stackoverflow sorry.

XPlot is a wrapper for both GoogleCharts and Plotly.  It also has been integrated with FSLab.

If you are using plotly use `open XPlot.Plotly`

google charts way:

```
let points =
sales |> Seq.ofList

points 
|> Chart.Scatter
|> Chart.Show
```

I messed around with things and I guess you actually don't need List.map.  It was just the first way.  Learning new things every day.

Comment: Thanks. Is this only for Plotly within XPlot or can it be applied to Google Charts?

Comment: I updated the answer.  Feel free to accept if it answers your question